# Getting class name without instanting an object

Tags: python

```
class A:
    pass

> A().__class__.__name__ 
-->'A'
> A.__class__.__name__
--> 'type'
```

How can I get `'A'` without the parens?

Comment: Use `A.__name__`.

Comment: Just found out from reviewing the jsonpickle code! D'oh!!!

Comment: please you should consider to google before posting such question,

Comment: @Roushan, that's the case for 96% of the questions ons SO.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `'type'`, because the class of a class definition is... `type` (in other words: a class definition is a type).

You can just use the `__name__` attribute. No need to look for the `__class__`, you already have *the class*:

```
A.__name__
```

> 'A'

---

Just to make it completely clear:

```
A().__class__ is A
```

> True